# Table height automatically increase in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show table in div, div height and width specified by user. If table height and width increases by div height and width then scroll bar is added. When i resize div by jquery resizable method then table height and width will be change.IN short i want to show table in div.  I write code for this, But its not working correctly.

Html code:-

http://jsfiddle.net/uhvL6fpe/

JQuery:-

```
  $(function(){
    $("grid_1").resizable().draggable();
       });
```

Comment: You want to manually be able to resize your table? You want also to drag the table???  And your fiddle is just copied from your html full of jQuery ui classes and you don't have any code there.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I paste code Here. My table is generated dynamically, And I put this table in div which has height and width. Now my table height is greater then div's height because it has very large data. Just for sowing purpose i copied my complete div code and paste in Jsfiddle.

Comment: For customize layout i added Jquery drag and resize event on this div. Now when i resizing my div, Then it's not affect my table.

Comment: I want like in this example (percentage based layout) http://quocity.com/colresizable/ but for both height and width.